# Rates of convergence in the functional CLT/weak invariance principle for martingale triangular arrays

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, limit-theorems

There are results for the rate of convergence of the functional CLT/weak invariance principle for martingales difference sequences, for example theorem 4.5 in the book *Martingale theory and its application* by Chris Heyde and Peter Hall.

However, I couldn't find such a result for martingale triangular arrays. Is there a fundamental reason to that, or could such results relatively easily be obtained from existing work?

Comment: You should look at https://arxiv.org/pdf/2107.02234.pdf

Comment: @MathIsLife12, thank you for your answer. The linked paper gives results for $\alpha$-mixing triangular arrays. If I understand correctly, martingales difference sequences need not be $\alpha$-mixing sequences. Am I missing something? Or is it that intermediate results in the paper you linked imply something for martingale triangular arrays?